# Get inner div to adapt to outer div width with padding

Tags: html, css

This might be a trivial question, but as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz0zt89k/) I have an inner and an outer div. The outer div has a percentage width on the body and the inner div should be exactly as wide as the outer div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, the inner div width does not adapt to the padding of the outer div. How do I get the inner div to do this?

The purpose of this is, that the div should be part of a form which consists of input fields and select boxes which also have a percentage width and a padding. The div should now be exactly as wide as the other form elements **with padding**.

Comment: So remove the left/right padding from the outer div?

Comment: or set the `margin:-10px;` to inner div

Comment: I can't. I need the div width to be 80% + 20px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container {
    width:80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed left and right padding.

Try this

```
#container {
    width:80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; //changed this
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mz0zt89k/1/)

Comment: But I need the padding as addition to the 80% width

Answer (score 0):

Just change the padding on the container. Also, block level elements will go to 100% width unless you specify otherwise.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKwoPJ

```
#container {
    width:80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px 0px; 
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left and right padding from the parent and add it to the child element. Using `box-sizing` with `border-box` will ensure that the `1px` border of the child will stay inside the parent element.

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
#container {
    width:80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the 20px too small.

Comment: I guess i have misunderstood your question then. Can you elaborate what it is that you are trying to achieve.  - *The problem is, the inner div width does not adapt to the padding of the outer div.*  So do you want the child div to have the same width as the parent div ? And do you  also want `10px` padding on each side, left and right for the child div or for the parent div? Your last paragraph is confusing. Is the child div part of the form and will it hold the input fields? `20px` is too small for what ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this css to the `#content` -

```
width: calc(100% + 20px);
margin-left: -10px;
```

Full Code -

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  margin-left: -10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#othercontent {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    I'm not following the padding
  </div>
  <div id="othercontent">
    I'm following..
  </div>
</div>
```